# WCF method returns DataSet and table's rows are out of order

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, dataset

I have a WCF service that returns a DataSet which contains 3 DataTables.  The first 2 DataTables contain some metadata about the data that will be processed, and the 3rd DataTable contains the main data to be processed.

In 99% of the clients, when the DataSet is retrieved from the webservice call, everything is in exactly the same order as it was server-side before the DataSet was sent.  However, at a few clients I've noticed that the rows of some of the DataTables are out of order.  Does anyone know why this might happen?

Please also, I do know all about the reasons everyone says not to use DataSets / DataTables over WCF, but for this project it is the right approach, so please no links to scary titled articles that say DataSets over WCF is the devil.

To solve the problem, I think I could probably just convert the DataSet to a byte array before I send it and back to a DataSet on the other end, or else I could just sort the DataTables at the client before I use them, but I'd still like to know why this happens in the first place; especially since I can't reproduce it outside of production.

Comment: One possibility exists that the messages sent are being received out of order.  If your clients framework for communicating with your service can support it, you could introduce Reliable Messaging to ensure the order that the messages are received from the client arrive in the same order sent. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480191.aspx

Comment: @GeorgeJohnston - Thanks for the reply; I thought the same thing, but can't prove it because I can't reproduce it and don't have the SOAP messages logged.  I appreciate the link.  Since this isn't a public webservice and I always know the client will be a .NET C# application, I think that Reliable Messaging would be a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You can try sending the XML by getting dataset.getXml() and rebuild dataset from client side.

[Dataset To XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.getxml.aspx) and [XML to Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd.aspx)

Comment: The documentation you provided a link to says the following...   "If you build a DataSet using schema inference and serialize it using XML or Web services, the column ordering may change.".  I think that's the cause of my problem in the first place, is that I'm sending a DataSet over WCF and it doesn't keep the order of columns correctly, and it looks like if you send it as XML it is saying the same thing might happen.  +1 for the link though, I think it does explain why the problem occurs in the first place.